# Why does the New Shepard Crew Capsule sometimes deploy 3 parachutes and sometimes deploys only 2 parachutes?

Tags: landing, parachute, new-shepard

The NS-18 capsule on Oct 13 2021 (with William Shatner aboard) landed with 3 parachutes deployed. In contrast, The NS-12 capsule on Dec 11 2019 landed with 2 parachutes deployed. Strangely in both videos, the terminal velocity of the landing capsule is the same, around 16 mph.

NS-18

NS-12

Comment: It seems you linked to the wrong video, since both videos clearly show three parachutes. Could you please link to the actual video of only two parachutes deploying?

Answer (score 4):

Because both capsules used THREE chutes?

[image]

The only New Shepard that landed on only two chutes was the june 2016 deliberate-parachute-failure test.